# Basic Javascript Variable Scoping

Tags: javascript, variables

So I'm trying to make an app that would return whether each of these twich users

```
  ["ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "storbeck", "habathcx",      "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"]
```

is streaming. This is my code:

```
var users= ["ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"];
var progress =0;
var streaming = [];
$(document).ready( function() {
console.log(window.progress);
while (window.progress<8) {


var url = 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/' + window.users[window.progress] + '?callback=?';
$.ajax({
url: url,
async: false,
dataType: 'json',
success: function(data) {
if (data.stream) {

window.streaming[window.progress]="streaming";

}
//if closed  
else {
window.streaming[window.progress]="not streaming";
};
//else closed

console.log(window.progress);
console.log(window.users[window.progress]);
var html = "<p> <a href=\" https://www.twitch.tv/"+window.users[window.progress] +" \" >"+window.users[window.progress]+ "</a> is currently " +window.streaming[window.progress] + "</p>";
$("body").append(html);
}});
// getjson closed
        window.progress +=1;
        };
// for loop closed

});

//document ready closed
```

and this is what I'm getting:

"undefined is currently streaming"

so it doesn't seem to pull the users. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your streaming array isn't initialized, so this can't be done due there's no 0,1,... element on it

```
window.streaming[window.progress]="streaming"; //streaming.length == 0, streaming[0] == 'undefined'
```

maybe you would like to clone the users.length on it to have a index

```
streaming = []; // length == 0
streaming.length = users.length; // length == users.length
```